# Django/Pythons is Messages - Unique Error displays the field

Tags: python, django, message

I am very new to Django/Python programming so hopefully this is a simple fix.

I have created a Model that when I try and add a duplicate record (via a ModelForm), the message that is returned to my template displays the unique field twice in the message. 
It appears like : "fieldname" "classname" with this "fieldname" already exists.

How do I display the fieldname once.

The message currently displayed is :
***FirstNamePerson with this FirstName already exists.***

What I would like to see is : ***Person with this FirstName already exists.***

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

Template.html

```
{% for message in messages %}
    <div class="alert alert-{{ message.tags }}">
        message: {{ message | striptags }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to get around this issue by using form.errors in the template rather than Django messages.

Using the below code in Template.html produces ***Person with this FirstName already exists.*** (which is what I am looking for)

```
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for key, value in form.errors.items %} 
        <div class="row testrow">
            <div class="alert alert-error col-lg-12">
                {{ value | striptags }}
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can catch the exception that is thrown for adding duplicate row and you can raise your own exception with custom message.

```
from django.db import IntegrityError

except IntegrityError as e: 
    if 'unique constraint' in e.message: # or e.args[0] from Django 1.10
        #do something, create exception with your own message.
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.primary_key), Django enforces uniqueness for primary keys, so the field must be unique throughout the table.

> **primary_key=True** implies **null=False** and **unique=True**. Only one primary
>   key is allowed on an object.

If you try to add a duplicate FirstName, you won't be able to and that's why you get that error.

By default Django adds an [AutoField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.AutoField) to hold the primary key, so you don’t need to set primary_key=True. It's actually bad practice to make a FirstName a primary_key.

So, as you still want to go ahead with it and change the error message, you can change your model to

```
class Person(models.Model):
    FirstName = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True, error_messages={'unique':"Person with this FirstName already exists."})
```

Comment: OP is aware of this and question is about custom exception message. This does not answer the question in anyway.

Comment: I know, was still writing the answer. Check again.

Comment: Thanks Tiago. I had tried this previously and continue to get the same error FirstNamePerson with this FirstName already exists.

Comment: Did you make the migrations?

Comment: I did make the migrations. I'm going to have a look into catching the exception as explained by Mahori. I'm new to this, but exception catching is something I need to get up to speed on so this forces my hand. Thanks

Comment: Even though it might sound redundant, did you test also adding `unique=True` to the field, migrated and checked again?